# Flutter webview has white space after using webkitColumnGap css

Tags: html, css, flutter, webview

[image]

I used following css so html can be horizontally scrolled,

```
  bodyElement.style.webkitColumnGap = paddingLeft + paddingRight + "px";
  bodyElement.style.webkitColumnWidth = pageWidth + "px";
  bodyElement.style.columnFill = "auto";
  bodyElement.style.margin = 0;
  htmlElement.style.height = pageHeight + (paddingTop + paddingBottom) + "px";
  bodyElement.style.height = pageHeight + "px";
```

Some of the values,

```
padding = 20, 20, 20, 20
window.innerWidth = 412
window.innerHeight = 604
clientWidth = 412
clientHeight = 604
bodyElement.offsetWidth = 412
bodyElement.offsetHeight = 8062
pageWidth = 372
pageHeight = 564
document.documentElement.offsetWidth = 412
```

Everything works fine html can be scrolled horizontally but I see lot of white-space in page showed in above image. Which gives vertical scroll bar. So on touch you can scroll vertically.

My first thought was to do the workaround just disable the vertical scrolling by using following css,

```
bodyElement.style.overflow = "hidden"; // didn't worked
```

Second thought was to add onscroll listener and return without scrolling also didn't worked,

```
htmlElement.onscroll = (e) => {
    Toaster.postMessage("-> html scroll event -> go back = ");
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  bodyElement.onscroll = (e) => {
    Toaster.postMessage("-> body scroll event -> go back = ");
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  window.onscroll = (e) => {
    Toaster.postMessage("-> window scroll event -> go back = ");
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

I have run out of ideas so would like help from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to remove the whitespace?

Comment: Yes. I want remove that white space.

Comment: how are you using web view? are you using webview plugin?

Comment: yes. flutter_webview not the one with plugin

Comment: `bodyElement.offsetHeight = 8062` to me this means that while the `pageHeight` is 465px tall, the body of the document is 8062px tall, hence the vertical scrollbar. What makes the body this tall???

Comment: `8062` is pre log stmt and `pageHeight = 564` is post log stmt. If you scroll all of that is just white space nothing else.

Comment: IS there any sample html string you are having for testing?. BTW, which plugin you are using?

Comment: flutter_webview and any html will do. Just add bunch big paragraph in html use my css.